# What is the difference between yarn and yarn install?

Tags: yarnpkg, apache-zeppelin, hdp

I am trying to install an additional plugin on Apache Zeppelin using Helium. The Installation command using by Helium to download this package is below:

```
com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'yarn install --fetch-retries=2 --fetch-retry-factor=1 --fetch-retry-mintimeout=5000 --registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/ --https-proxy=http://SVC_Hxxxxxp:***@webguard.xxxxx.no:8080 --proxy=http://SVC_Hxxxop:***@webguard.xxxxx.no:8080' failed. (error code 1)
```

**Version installed:**

```
node -v
v8.1.1


npm -v
5.0.3

mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9
```

How cmd will be able to identify if it is yarn or yarn install ?

Answer (score 42):

Running yarn with no command will run yarn install, passing through any provided flags.

Comment: reference: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/

Answer (score 34):

Directly taken from the doc:

> yarn install is used to install all dependencies for a project. This
>   is most commonly used when you have just checked out code for a
>   project, or when another developer on the project has added a new
>   dependency that you need to pick up.
>
> If you are used to using npm you might be expecting to use --save or
>   --save-dev. These have been replaced by yarn add and yarn add --dev. For more information, see the yarn add documentation.
>
> **Running yarn with no command will run yarn install, passing through
>   any provided flags.**

**Conclusion:**

It's not the `cmd` to determine what to do (whether invoke `yarn` or `yarn install`), it's determined by the `yarn` itself. [Plese read more](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/). There are a lot to learn/understand.